# Is it possible to convert .rar into .zip in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, file-conversion

I have `.rar` file on Google Drive.
I need to convert it into `.zip`.

Is it possible to do so in Google Drive?
W/o downloading a file locally, converting and uploading back again.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible at all without downloading it first. File extensions can be renamed, however, it will still be a `RAR.rar` file just called `ZIP.zip` (and if you download it will be `Zip.zip.rar`). Also, keep in mind that it's not just about the extension. The structure of RAR is way too different than ZIP.

Comment: Surely it could be possible with an app script?